# Cómo corregir este error con pdo en php?

Tags: php, pdo

El error es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method PDO::prepare() cannot
> be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\www\System HOD
> V1.7\modelo\login-clase.php:22 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\www\System HOD
> V1.7\controlador\login-controlador.php(17): ingresar->datosUsuario()
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\www\System HOD V1.7\app\controlador.php(25): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\www\System HOD V1.7\index.php(17):
> Controlador->Controlador() #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\www\System HOD V1.7\modelo\login-clase.php
> on line 22

Mi código es:

```
    class ingresar extends DB
{
    private $conex;

    public function __construct()
    {$this->conex = parent::__construct();}

    public function getConex()
    {return $this->conex;}

    public function datosUsuario()
    {

        $tabla = "SELECT * FROM usuario";

        $respuestaArreglo = '';
        try {
            $datos = BD::prepare($tabla);
            $datos->execute();
            $datos->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $respuestaArreglo = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $respuestaArreglo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $errorReturn = ['estatus' => false];
            $errorReturn += ['info' => "error sql:{$e}"];
            return $errorReturn;
        }
    }

}
?>
define('HOST', 'localhost');
  define('BD', 'HOD');
  define('USER', 'postgres');
  define('PASSWORD', '26142326');
  define('PORT', '5432');
  define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

class BD extends PDO
{

private $host;
private $db;
private $user;
private $password;
private $port;
private $charset;

public function __construct()
{

    $this->host     = constant('HOST');
    $this->db       = constant('BD');
    $this->user     = constant('USER');
    $this->password = constant('PASSWORD');
    $this->port     = constant('PORT');
    $this->charset  = constant('CHARSET');

    try {

        $conexion = parent::__construct('pgsql:host=' . $this->host . ' ; port=' . $this->port . '; dbname=' . $this->db . ';  user=' . $this->user . '; password=' . $this->password);

        $this->repetirconexion = true;
        $this->errorconexion   = "";

    } catch (PDOException $e) {$this->errorconexion = "Error de Conexion en: " . $e;}
}

public function getRepetirConexion()
{return $this->repetirconexion;}

public function getErrorConexion()
{return $this->errorconexion;}
}
```

---

esta es la conexion que estoy usando

```
class BD extends PDO
```

{

```
private $host;
private $db;
private $user;
private $password;
private $port;
private $charset;

public function __construct()
{

    $this->host     = constant('HOST');
    $this->db       = constant('BD');
    $this->user     = constant('USER');
    $this->password = constant('PASSWORD');
    $this->port     = constant('PORT');
    $this->charset  = constant('CHARSET');

    try {

        $conexion = parent::__construct('pgsql:host=' . $this->host . ' ; port=' . $this->port . '; dbname=' . $this->db . ';  user=' . $this->user . '; password=' . $this->password);

        $this->repetirconexion = true;
        $this->errorconexion   = "";

    } catch (PDOException $e) {$this->errorconexion = "Error de Conexion en: " . $e;}
}

public function getRepetirConexion()
{return $this->repetirconexion;}

public function getErrorConexion()
{return $this->errorconexion;}
```

}

Comment: Agrega tu clase BD, aunque el error ahi es claro no puedes llamar de forma estática `::` al método `prepare`

Comment: No entiendo mucho la forma en que organizas tus clases. Realmente el mismo nombre de la clase `ingresar` ya debería hacerte pensar que eso **debería ser un método, no un clase**. No por casualidad, en POO se recomienda que **los métodos lleven nombres de verbos** y las clases lleven nombre de sustantivos (Persona, Casa, Empleado). Si no diseñas las clases con ese criterio claro, rápidamente tendrás un spaghetti en tu código. Ese es el principal problema que veo, aunque hay un error real, el origen del mismo está en la lógica que estás implementando (diseño erróneo del modelo de datos).

Comment: lamentablemente asi fue como nos enseñaron en la unversidad por eso pensaba que se hacia asi, ademas la forma de usar el prepare ya me habia funcionado en otro sistema, los errores que me esta dando el PDO es desde que cambie la conexion ,